# Pair of dice and a dictionary

Tags: python

So, I have a pair of dice. I roll them together. I want all the possible outcomes (More like P&C). There is going to be a total of 36 outcomes. For Eg: (1,1),(2,5) etc.
Now I want to store these in a dictionary as tuples.

I want the outcome to be:

```
A = {1:(1,1), 2:(1,2),3:(1,3).....,36:(6,6)}
```

I have two approaches for this: Dictionary Comprehension or the traditional looping.

The Dictionary Comprehension goes like:

```
from itertools import product
dice = {k:i for i in list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) for k in range(1,37)}
```

This gives me the output as

```
{1: (6, 6), 2: (6, 6),....,36:(6,6)}
```

As soon as I interchange the positions of "k" and "i", I get

```
{(1, 1): 36, (1, 2): 36,.....,(6, 6): 36}
```

This got me confused. I'm not entirely sure what's happening here! I tried the same with looping and I got the same output. I'm sure something's wrong here and I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: That's not unexpected. I'm not able to understand, after the swapping, why the tuple ( the key) started iterating as it was supposed to and the value got stuck at 36?

Comment: Write your code as a traditional loop and print the intermediate results. You'll see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're requesting a nested loop here, which is causing multiple definitions of the same keys, and you're seeing the latest value for that key only.

What you actually want to do is to `zip` the output of the two functions.

Code sample:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> {k:i for i in list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) for k in range(1,37)}
{1: (6, 6), 2: (6, 6), 3: (6, 6), 4: (6, 6), 5: (6, 6), 6: (6, 6), 7: (6, 6), 8: (6, 6), 9: (6, 6), 10: (6, 6), 11: (6, 6), 12: (6, 6), 13: (6, 6), 14: (6, 6), 15: (6, 6), 16: (6, 6), 17: (6, 6), 18: (6, 6), 19: (6, 6), 20: (6, 6), 21: (6, 6), 22: (6, 6), 23: (6, 6), 24: (6, 6), 25: (6, 6), 26: (6, 6), 27: (6, 6), 28: (6, 6), 29: (6, 6), 30: (6, 6), 31: (6, 6), 32: (6, 6), 33: (6, 6), 34: (6, 6), 35: (6, 6), 36: (6, 6)}
>>> {k:i for i,k in zip(list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)), range(1,37))}
{1: (1, 1), 2: (1, 2), 3: (1, 3), 4: (1, 4), 5: (1, 5), 6: (1, 6), 7: (2, 1), 8: (2, 2), 9: (2, 3), 10: (2, 4), 11: (2, 5), 12: (2, 6), 13: (3, 1), 14: (3, 2), 15: (3, 3), 16: (3, 4), 17: (3, 5), 18: (3, 6), 19: (4, 1), 20: (4, 2), 21: (4, 3), 22: (4, 4), 23: (4, 5), 24: (4, 6), 25: (5, 1), 26: (5, 2), 27: (5, 3), 28: (5, 4), 29: (5, 5), 30: (5, 6), 31: (6, 1), 32: (6, 2), 33: (6, 3), 34: (6, 4), 35: (6, 5), 36: (6, 6)}
```

Comment: You could even drop the call to `list` in the second example.

Answer (score 3):

```
dice = {k:i for i in list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)) for k in range(1,37)}
```

This is trying to create a dict with every number from 1 to 36 mapping to every tuple in your product.

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up your keys and values

```
dice = {k:i for i,k in zip(product(range(1,7), repeat=2), range(1,37))}
```

which is more simply

```
dice = dict(zip(range(1,37), product(range(1,7), repeat=2)))
```

Or you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate the indexes:

```
dice = dict(enumerate(product(range(1,7), repeat=2), 1))
```

Comment: If we're code-golfing this, you can also use `enumerate` and get rid of the `range` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that.

```
from itertools import product

dice = {}
for k, i in enumerate(product(range(1,7), repeat=2)):
    dice[k] = i
```